# What does Smash Mouth mean when he writes "fed to the rules" in All-Star?

Tags: meaning, song-lyrics, smash-mouth

So the first two lines of the pre-chorus of [All-Star](https://genius.com/Smash-mouth-all-star-lyrics) by Smash Mouth the song goes:

> Well, the years start coming and they don't stop coming
> Fed to the rules and I hit the ground running

What does Smash Mouth mean when he writes "fed to rules"? The analysis in Genius says that "'Fed to the rules' is reminiscent of the saying 'fed to the wolves,' implying that society attempted to sacrifice his individuality for the sake of maintaining their social order." I don't know if it's correct though since the full answer given on Genius feels contradictory. They go onto say "Instead of giving in, the speaker’s immediate reaction was to “run” and escape this typical life and all its rules" which doesn't make sense given the phrase "hit the ground running" doesn't mean to run *away*. Can someone explain?